# combine multiple tables by adding columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have table one

```
Key     sKey    Amount      HOURS
84554   0       32789.87    0.00
84717   0       18273.64    0.00
85077   0       201.84      0.00
85081   0       186.53      0.00
```

And table two

```
Key     sKey    Item1       
84554   0       11.11   
84717   0       22.22   
85077   0       33.33       
85081   0       44.44
```

How can I get a table like

```
Key     sKey    Amount      HOURS   Item1
84554   0       32789.87    0.00    11.11
84717   0       18273.64    0.00    22.22
85077   0       201.84      0.00    33.33
85081   0       186.53      0.00    44.44
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Google `sql inner join`. In your case you want to join on `key`.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because lack of research and effort (no attempted code at all).

Comment: This question is so basic that i don't find duplicates.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM   ONE INNER JOIN TWO 
       ON  ONE.Key  = TWO.Key 
       AND ONE.sKey = TWO.sKey
```